# Let $P$ an irreducible polynomial. How can $\gcd(P',P)=P$?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Let $P$ an irreducible polynomial. How can $\gcd(P',P)=P$ ? Let $P(X)=a_nX^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+...+a_0$ irreducible. To me, $$P'(X)=na_nX^{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+...+a_1,$$
and thus, how can $\gcd(P,P')=P$ ?

Comment: The equality can't hold due to degrees.

Comment: I know, that's why I ask the question. May be if the characteristic is not $0$ ? @GitGud

Comment: In only one case: $P'=0$, which supposes we're in prime characteristic $p$ and $P(X)=F(X^p)$.

Comment: @Bernard: I can buy that. Thank you :-)

Comment: @Rick: It's totally free :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a specific example consider $K=\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, the field of rational functions over the field with $p$ elements, and $P= X^p + t$.

More generally,  (as remarked in a comment) one can show that $P'$ must be $0$ and thus $P(X) = F(X^p)$ for some other polynomial.

Further note that over a finite field $F(X^p)= G(X)^p$ for some polynomial $G$, so that such a polynomial will never be irreducible.

However if the Frobenius map $K\to K$, given by $a \mapsto a^p$ is not an automorphism then one can construct example, as shown at the start.